# show up VS appear

Tags: word-usage

Do they mean the same?

1. He showed up neither in my office nor in the cafe.
2. He appeared neither in my office nor in the cafe.

Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Yes, but 'show up' is informal, but 'appear' is not.

Comment: Your phrasing is formal / literary / poetic. Most people in most contexts would use explicit negation with do-support: *He **didn't** show up in my office or the cafe* (or ***turn up*** or ***come to*** - the verb ***appear*** is also a bit "literary" for most contexts like this).

Comment: What about  "A rainbow appeared in the sky." "A rainbow showed up in the sky." I was taught that "appear"means showing up suddenly, and the subjects could be someone or something. On the other hand, to show up means appearing as expected, and the subjects should be someone. Is it correct?

Comment: Something can show up unexpectedly. _She showed up unexpectedly at the match._ (Cambridge Dictionary).

Comment: I've heard "show up to work" Can we use "appear to work?" since it looks like they are the same.

Comment: I would use 'appear **at** work', since appear **to** work can mean 'seem to work, while not doing anything'.